# Create label for conical surface

Tags: ms-word

Is it possible to create labels for conical surfaces in MS-word.
I have a label ready, but it needs to adapt to that the printed label can be pasted on a conical surface (e.g. a coffee cup)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. You could try using WordArt: these are predefined shapes, maybe one of those matches what you want to do.
I suspect you'd be better off using a program like Adobe Illustrator, which can convert text to vector images which you can distort any way you like.
The bigger problem is that the label won't fit properly on a shape that is curved in two dimensions: you'll always have folds somewhere.